# Reading ensdf files

Tags: soft-question, nuclear-physics, computational-physics, software, data

I understand that this is more of a computing question, but I still think the appropriate place to ask it is here.

The Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data Files are on the internet, available for public use, and viewable online: http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/

You can view any dataset online, or download them.

My question is, after I download a dataset, what application can I use to view it? I've tried searching on the internet for an appropriate application but nothing obvious crops up. Anyone who's previously needed to analyze nuclear data files will perhaps have used these datasets and may know how to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They open as text files after you unzip them.
You can open them with excel to parse the data

Comment: After I unzip them they appear to just be files that have no extension. Am I doing something wrong? I'm downloading and extracting as I usually would. I can open these files then in word or notepad but the formatting is horrible and very difficult to read. I can similarly open them in excel but as before the formatting is just terrible. I'm hoping for a method that will end up with the data opening in a similar style to the "View in web format" option on the website itself.

Comment: When you open them in excel do you specify a delimiter such as a coma or tab ?

Comment: No! But I do now. Seems to work well enough. I think that's as good an answer as I'll get, thank you.